# Server terminate from infinite while loop?

Tags: java, client, client-server

I'm totally new in java.

I started to learn java network programming.

My problem: i put my server in infinite while loop to keep working.

I send a message to the server, when the server reads this message it should perform some action. it is performed successfully but after exiting my client program, the server also terminates although i put it in infinite while loop.

my client code:

```
private void check_ordersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        Socket ss = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
        PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        pr.println("Supplier Orders");
        pr.println(Supplier.username);
        pr.close();
        this.dispose();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(supp_page.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

my server code:

```
    int iiiiii = 0;
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(4000); 
    String request = null;
    while(iiiiii == 0)
    {
        Socket ss = s1.accept();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));
        request = in.readLine();

        switch (request) {
            case "Supplier Orders":
                Supplier.username = in.readLine();
                orders rs = new orders();
                rs.setLocation(350, 250);
                rs.setSize(800, 350);
                rs.setVisible(true);
                rs.setTitle("Orders Table");
                rs.setResizable(false);
                break;

                // some other messages here but iam focus on above one
        }
     }
```

let me explain more: when i call this method it send a message to the client "Supplier Orders" and a username .... when server receives this message it should launch a gui page that contains some data of the that supplier i gave username to the server.

but when i close client the server also terminates ... that should not be happened. i want the server to keep working and not exit.

so how to fix this ? .. sorry for long post.

**Edit**

The code for gui page, it should show some data on table: it showed data successfully but as i mention when i close client, the server also closed which i don't want to happen, i want server to keep working not to **close**

```
public class orders extends javax.swing.JFrame {

DefaultTableModel t = new DefaultTableModel();
public orders() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    initComponents();
    request.setModel(t);
    t.addColumn("ID");
    t.addColumn("PRODUCT Name");
    t.addColumn("PRODUCT TYPE");
    t.addColumn("PRODUCT QUANTITY");
    t.addColumn("SUPPLIER ID");
    t.addColumn("SUPPLIER NAME");
    t.addColumn("SUPPLIER COMPANY");
    t.addColumn("SUPPLIER ADDRESS");
    t.addColumn("SUPPLIER PHONE NUMBER");
    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Orders.bin"));
    ArrayList<Order> a = (ArrayList)oin.readObject();
    Iterator<Order> iter = a.iterator();
    oin.close();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Order r = iter.next();
        if(Supplier.username.equals(r.getP().getS().getId() + r.getP().getS().getCompany()) && r.getStatus().equals("PENDING"))
        {
            t.addRow(new Object[]{r.getP().getId(),r.getP().getName(),r.getP().getType(),r.getP().getQuantity(),r.getP().getS().getId()
            ,r.getP().getS().getName(), r.getP().getS().getCompany(), r.getP().getS().getAddress(), r.getP().getS().getPhone_no()});
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Couple of things stand out, but I need to know your desired behavior. Do you only want to handle one client at a time or serve multiple client at the same time?  When client stops, `in.readLine()` will throw an exception, which I don't see you handling, so this is most likely why program is stopping.  Also, you should separate accepting socket from servicing it.

Comment: my program is running on localhost, so maybe to handle only one client. but is this cause the server to close ... i have other messages on the same server like this and it is working perfectly ... server not exiting even if i close the client. but i don't know the reason why server is closing on that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your client is closing the socket between the client and server when the client exits as DBug said. Since you're blocking on the in.readline() in the server an IOException (Socket Closed Exception) is thrown. Your code is not handling that IOException and your while loop won't be enough to prevent the server code from exiting. You need to add a few try/catches to catch these exceptions.

Consider adding a few finally blocks to ensure your sockets and streams get closed properly.

Comment: That was really helpful sir and +1 to your answer ... but i still need your help if you can ... i have added `finally` blocks and discovered closing sockets automatically and my question is: how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The easiest pattern is to open the socket then enter a while loop while servicing the socket. If you want to keep retrying the connection then wrap all of that code with another while loop to retry connection. While you want to connect, connect to socket, while socket is open, service socket.